# Xamarin.iOS Visual Studio 2019/2022 not showing simulators in Mac

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2019 & 2022 Community but both not showing any simulators in the Mac. If I plugged in my iPhone on the Mac, I am able to see it. Yet I am not able to see the simulator. I need to use different simulator to generate screenshot for the AppStore. Any advise?

*Note 1: I have installed both iOS 14 and 15 in the Mac and simulator still not showing.*

*Note 2: I think my Mac automatically updated my XCode to 13, then everything not working.*

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. Any solutions ?

Comment: Yes, I have posted my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/568996/ios-simulators-on-not-showing-in-vs2019-for-window.html

This is due to the update in MAC, download the xamarin.ios-15.0.0.6.pkg from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12778 in the MAC and install it. Then it'll be OK.